# How to hide an Azure App Service Slot from the internet

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have "build" slot for my website hosted on azure app services. I was wondering it it would be possible to not make it available under any url. i.e. I don't want the "build" slot deployment reachable using http://mysite-build.azurewebsite.net

Answer (score 1):

Create An Azure Vnet. Create a network security group to restrict access on that specific Vnet. Deploy your WEB APP inside the Vnet. For more info 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-overview/

Comment: That won't change the listening behavior for the Web App, public facing 80/TCP and 443/TCP will still answer requests. VNET integration provides a way to originate requests from your Web App, travel over the Point-to-Site VPN and reach other resources either in the VNET or on premises (over Site-to-Site VPN). `<ipSecurity>` would be an alternative to a GUID, if you sit on a somewhat known public IP range.

Comment: I agree with you that Vnet Alone will not provide the solution in this case. But please look at my answer carefully. I talked about creating a NSG(Network security group), which actually controls your incoming and Outgoing traffic within a Vnet. Please go through https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/network-security-groups/

Comment: Here's what i mean. http://i.imgur.com/ePnlOOd.png  -- An NSG is controlling traffic in/out a subnet, but your Web App (in App Service multi-tenant) does not sit on a subnet in the VNET.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a great way to do this.

One approach would be to give the slot a guid based name, e.g. build992ecdf6-0868-488c-952e-1c2aa16dd23b. While still technically available, it is effectively unguessable.

Comment: Am more worried about google stumbling across it and indexing my content under the other url

Comment: Google can only find places that are linked to from somewhere. Azure will never publicly advertise your slot url, so I don't see how they would index it.

Comment: Best idea I can come up with thus far is adding a slot variable that would add a NOINDEX into the header of the website. Not ideal, at least google will leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use AppServiceEnvironment. Its really costly to be adapted for small or medium sized apps. [ASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic)